# Use of Disabled fields in HTML

Tags: html

I came across a text that data inside disabled fields is not submitted along with the form. So i don't see why we even need to use disabled fields while writing code. Please explain the scenario in which it becomes inevitable to use disabled field.

Comment: For conditions where you don't want that field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A field that is `disabled` in an HTML form is unusable, unclickable and will not submit data.

The point about such a field is that *something else has to happen* before that field is no longer `disabled` - and then it becomes a normal HTML form field.

**eg.**

```js
var otherReasonRadio = document.querySelector('input[value="reason-other"]');
var otherReasonInput = document.querySelector('input[name="other-reason"]');

function enableOtherReasonInput() {
otherReasonInput.removeAttribute('disabled');
}

otherReasonRadio.addEventListener('change',enableOtherReasonInput,false);
```

```css
label {
display: block;
}
```

```html
<form>
<label><input type="radio" name="reason" value="reason-a" />Reason A</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="reason" value="reason-b" />Reason B</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="reason" value="reason-other" />Other Reason</label>

<p><label>Please State Other Reason: <input type="text" name="other-reason" disabled></label></p>
</form>
```

Comment: ok.. i ran the code snippet.. and it did become enabled after selecting other reason radiobutton.. but when i am selecting another radio button, should it not become disabled again? I think adding one more event listener will do the trick.. please confirm

Comment: Yes, you can add another event listener and another function to ensure that when any other radio button is selected the text input once again becomes `disabled`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say, we have `user` with `name`, `username`, `email` and `type`. Now we need a single html form for both editing existing user and adding new user. While editing we don't want the `email` of the user to be modified. So, we can disable this field when you are editing `user`. Because, we actually don't want it to be submitted to the server or any other form processor. On the other hand, while adding the user, we need the `email` field to be added. So, while adding, we shouldn't disable the `email` field. That's just an example why we need to disable a field. Same form, but while editing, no `email` will be submitted, while adding `email` will be submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Conditions in which you want to show the field but do not want to be submitted along the rest form fields